# react leaflet draw - editing a polygon and updating polygon state doesn't work as expected

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have an array of polygons set as state. I want to show them using Leaflet and edit the polygons. Polygon state must change, so I can store them in a database later on.

Problem is: if I edit an existing polygon, the first time I edit and save, all is going well. State is changed. The second time, the handles are moved, but the polygon state isn't updated.

A workaround that I have found is:
if you push the editbutton the second time, followed by cancel, then push edit again, then all works as expected.
It is not a proper workaround off course :-(

see my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, FeatureGroup, Polygon } from "react-leaflet";
import { EditControl } from "react-leaflet-draw";
import "leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css";

export default function Zones() {
    const _polygon1 = {
        id: 1,
        latlngs: [
            [51.515, 5.09],
            [52.52, 5.1],
            [51.52, 6.12],
        ],
    };
    const _polygon2 = {
        id: 2,
        latlngs: [
            [52, 6.09],
            [52.52, 6.1],
            [52.52, 7.12],
        ],
    };

    const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState([_polygon1, _polygon2]);

    const onEdited = (layers) => {
        //polygons that are changed are stored in changedPolys array
        const changedPolys = Object.values(layers._layers).map((layer) => {
            const latlngs = layer._latlngs[0].map((latlng) => {
                return [latlng.lat, latlng.lng];
            });
            return { id: layer.options.id, latlngs: latlngs };
        });

        //update state of all the polygons. replace polygons with changedPolys
        changedPolys.forEach((changedPoly) => {
            setPolygons((polygons) => {
                return polygons.map((polygon) => {
                    if (polygon.id === changedPoly.id) {
                        return { id: changedPoly.id, latlngs: changedPoly.latlngs };
                    }
                    return polygon;
                });
            });
        });
    };

    console.log(polygons);

    return (
        <MapContainer style={{ height: "100%" }} center={[52.1, 5.1]} zoom={9}>
            <FeatureGroup>
                <EditControl
                    position="topright"
                    onEdited={(e) => onEdited(e.layers)}
                    draw={{ marker: false, circlemarker: false, polyline: false, rectangle: false, circle: false }}
                />

                {polygons?.map((polygon) => {
                    return (
                        <Polygon
                            key={polygon.id}
                            id={polygon.id}
                            positions={polygon.latlngs}
                            pathOptions={{ color: polygon.id === 1 ? "black" : "red" }}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </FeatureGroup>

            <TileLayer url={""} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

see this issue: https://github.com/alex3165/react-leaflet-draw/issues/114
same problem, with a possible solution that I totally not understand.
Is there a way to solve this?

I have created a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-tree-su8yun?file=/src/App.js